# Grails get domain object from database based on field with type as another domain type

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Say I want to get `book`s by `author`s who have "john" in their name. How could I do something like:

```
Book.createCriteria().list(){
    like('author.name', '%john%')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a Book is related to Author you should be able to do the following:

```
Book.createCriteria().list() {
  author {
    like('name', '%john%')
  }
}
```

You can read more about Querying Associations in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#querying).